# How do I keep the lastest entry of an item from a database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

In my database, I have, let's say, a HUGE collection of meteo broadcast.

I would like to get all the meteobroadcast from a particular city, for example, but return only the LATEST entry of meteo broadcast instead of all of them. So I would get a list of meteo broadcast from all the town / district in the city.

So let's say I have this method:

```
internal List<METEO> ListLatestMeteoByRegion(int _id)
{
    var meteoQry = from meteo in db.METEO
                   where meteo.REGION.REGIONID == _id
                   // SORT METEO BY DATETIME???
                   select meteo;

    List<METEO> listToReturn = new List<METEO>;

    listToReturn.AddRange(meteoQry);
}
```

and METEO is this model:

```
public class METEO
{
    public int METEOID { get; set;} 

    public int REGIONDID { get; set; }

    public Region region { get;set; }

    public int DISTRICTID { get; set; }

    public District district { get; set;}

    public DateTime DATEMETEOBROADCAST { get; set; }

    public string METEOOUTSIDE { get; set;}
}
```

Now this is incomplete as the meteo database may have many entries from the same city in a same day, and I'd like to get the absolute latest at all time. As well, it may "not" get any entry for a few days because of some lazy guys (you get the idea).

How could I check the database to make sure that I only get and keep the latest entry of such a meteo broadcast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question.  This query would return the most recent record for your `REGIONID`:

```
var meteoQry = (from meteo in db.METEO
                   where meteo.REGION.REGIONID == _id
                   orderby meteo.DATEMETEOBROADCAST descending
                   select meteo).First();
```

In the link that Jason posted in the comments, keep in mind:

> The First(IEnumerable) method throws an exception if
>   source contains no elements. To instead return a default value when
>   the source sequence is empty, use the FirstOrDefault method.

EDIT:

Per Herve's comment, the code above will return one object and not a List<>.  If you would like to use a list instead (with just one item), try:

```
var meteoQry = (from meteo in db.METEO
                   where meteo.REGION.REGIONID == _id
                   orderby meteo.DATEMETEOBROADCAST descending
                   select meteo).Take(1);
```

Comment: A question: I'm not used to c# ASP.NET and linq, so why the `.First();?`

Comment: It will return the First record.  But it will always expect at least ONE record.  If there's a chance of there being ZERO records, you should use `FirstOrDefault` which will typically return the first record or null.

Comment: But this will not return a list of items, rather one item. Or the original query ought to return a list, which is not really what the "First()" allow me to do...

Comment: Why would you want to return a list when you really only get one object?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a view if you can in the db called `vwLatestMeteoDateMetroBroadcast` that has something like this:

```
Select REGIONID, DATEMETEOBROADCAST
From meteo.REGION
Group By REGIONID
```

You can then join `meteo.Region` with `meteo.vwLatestMeteoDateMetroBroadcast` to get the most recent one

(assuming you never have multiple rows from the same region with the exact same `DATEMETEOBROADCAST`)